# Llattice diamond programmer-tool

Tags: vhdl, libusb, lattice-diamond

install Lattice Diamond 3.10 on my computer with Manjaro 17.1 and everything works correctly just because of a problem. The programming tool does not work, when I try to execute it I get a window with a message:

> "can not load library: 
>   /usr/local/diamond/3.10_x64/bin/lin64/toolapps/libdvmapp.so:
>   (libusb-0.1.so.4: the shared object file can not be opened: the file
>   does not exist or the directory)"

already downloaded and I put the library in the corresponding directory but still does not let me run it

Any suggestions to solve it, I would appreciate it very much
Thank you

[image: 1]

Comment: apt-get install libusb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the following libraries:

> `libusb 1.0.21-2
>   libgusb 0.2.11-1
>   libusb-compat 0.1.5-1
>   libusbmuxd 1.0.10+13dc724e70-1`

And the programming tool works

Comment: If you'd read the [software documentation](http://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/InstallationGuides/Diamond/Diamond38_Installation_Guide_for_Linux.ashx?document_id=51751&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiGv9jZhZnaAhXFKlAKHTe_BC0QFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw2CS1c6tU20PkJgYtlmT8SN), you'd found a list of library dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

I already had all of the dependencies listed by Cristian in place. I had to install libusb-dev and it worked.

```
sudo apt install libusb-dev
```